# IMAP - fetching the previous and next UIDs

Tags: email, imap

Using standard spec IMAP commands, how can I determine the previous and next UIDs in a mailbox based on a passed UID, sorting the mailbox messages by date, newest first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way would be to ask for all UIDs first:

```
UID SEARCH ALL
```

...and sort. Each message added to the mailbox is assigned a higher UID than the messages which were added previously.

So higher UID = newer email.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was afraid of. Reason being this is a fairly expensive command to execute, mainly for large mailboxes (10K+ messages) which some users of the system (read: gmail accounts) will have. I was hoping there was a more efficient way to get this data.

Comment: It's not expensive at all. For mailbox with 10399 emails it takes 
0,254 seconds to execute and create a list of longs. At least with Mail.dll

Comment: It's O(entire mailbox), so of course it's fast for a small mailbox such as 10339 messages. Generally it's best to avoid O(entire mailbox) implementations of O(single messages) tasks.

Comment: @arnt Question is about previous and next uids (presumably all).

Answer (score 8):

I have found **new mail UID** with below code.

```
   @Override
        public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent e) {
         try {
             long newMailUID = ((IMAPFolder) e.getSource()).getUIDNext()
         } catch (MessagingException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }
       }
```

Comment: The question is not about UID NEXT, but previous and next uids.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that "sorting the mailbox messages by date, newest first" refers to the time the messages were *added* to the mailbox rather than `INTERNALDATE` or the `Date` header:

```
A001 SEARCH UID 82342
* SEARCH 83
A001 OK SEARCH completed

A002 FETCH 82,84 UID
* FETCH 82 (UID 82309)
* FETCH 84 (UID 82343)
A002 OK FETCH completed
```

Things to look out for:

- If the UID doesn't exist in the mailbox, `SEARCH` will return no results.
- If the UID matched the first/last message in the mailbox, don't try to fetch the one before/after or you'll get a `BAD` response.

If you'd prefer not to use `SEARCH`, you could also do the UID-to-sequence via `UID FETCH`:

```
A001 UID FETCH 82342 UID
* FETCH 83 (UID 82342)
A001 OK UID FETCH completed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for the UID before 12345, this command will do it:

```
a UID SEARCH RETURN (MAX) UID 1:12344
```

Finding the next after:

```
b UID SEARCH RETURN (MIN) UID 12346:*
```

This requires the [ESEARCH extension](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4731), which most modern servers implement. Notably gmail implements it. It's a little too expensive to issue in a loop, though, so perhaps you're better off solving your issue in another way. Here's a two-command sequence to get the 50 UIDs immediately preceding 12345:

```
c1 SEARCH UID 12345
* SEARCH 1000
c1 OK done
c2 UID SEARCH 950:999
* SEARCH 12200,12202,...
c2 OK done
```

950 is "result of c1 - 50", 999 is "result of c1 - 1".

Answer (score -3):

I'm not familiar with the exact commands, but have you checked out the RFC?

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501

Looks like there is a UIDNEXT command you can send that gives you the next UID.

Comment: Actually, i'm pretty sure that the UIDNEXT response is only returned by the SELECT/EXAMINE commands on a specified mailbox, and it refers to the UID that will be given to the next message that gets added to that mailbox. I'm looking for the the next/previous UIDs of existing messages in a mailbox, relative to a passed UID. This would be implemented when viewing a message to enable navigating to the next/previous message.

Comment: UIDNEXT is not related to what the OP is asking.